I would like to check the grammar and the meaning of a sentence with actions in the future and with the pronoun 'yours'
Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

When I change other things, I will remember this precious advice of yours.

I have found this translation from my language to English and I have 2 doubts about the correctness of it:

with When I change other things.. I want to write When I'll change other things.. so an action in the future. Is it correct to use the present (When I change)?

with this precious advice of yours I would like to say this precious advice which you have given to me. The translation maintains the meaning which I would like to give it?



I'll let others elaborate more, but yes, it's valid to use present tense along with "when" for future events, like "When the clock strikes midnight." And yes, the context makes it clear that "advice of yours" means "advice you gave me," since any other meaning is unlikely.

Thank you very much

There are a lot of existing questions about what tense follows when, and yes it's the present. 1 2

@StuartF thank you for the links. I didn't search a lot about present tense and in my mind I have two problems in this sentence: 'present tense' and the use of pronoun 'yours'.


It would be wrong to say "when I will [x], I will [y]" because you can't use 'will' twice in a time clause like that. The main clause is the timing of the subordinate clause. It has to be when [x] happens, [y] will happen.

They both mean the same thing, essentially. Saying "this advice of yours" gives ownership of the advice to the other party. It could infer that they always give that advice, that they live by it themselves. On the other hand, "this advice you gave me" could suggest the advice was bespoke, given to you only. They don't definitely mean either of those things - but that's the subtle difference in language.


